# Ajax/jQuery links not loading properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm currently using the jQuery/Ajax page load script, to fire my web pages into a div tag (rather than refreshing the page each time).

I've just started to notice though that any links inside the pages that are being loaded in, will not display their destination in the same div?

Idea:

Link 1 on the home page > loads into main content div tag > click another link on the content that has just loaded from link 1 > loads into main div tag.. however right now, it just opens it as a new page.

The way the links are taught/called is via `<ul id="style"><li>link</li></ul>` tags.

The coding from the non-link working page is the following:

```
<ul id="t-endnav">

            <li><a href="lukeberry.php">Luke Berry</a></li><br />
            <li><a href="click.php">Click Radio</a></li>

</ul>
```

You can find the website at: http://colourednoise.co.uk/site/22/chrome.php - the page is under "Portfolio" and both "Click Radio" & "Luke Berry" should be loading their pages in-place of the current content displayed from "Portfolio".

Any idea where I'm going wrong? It's turn my head to pieces today..

Comment: can i see your jQuery code? I have a nagging suspicion you aren't using a callback function.

Comment: yeah sorry, I forgot to post it.

http://pastebin.com/YWeEKQNv

Comment: i gave a terribly simplistic response, but looking at your pastebin callbacks it doesn't include function u want to do to the dynamically loaded links. Without having it in a callback function, your code won't see the new content.

Answer (score 2):

All content loaded in through AJAX needs to have methods applied to that new content done in the callback function. Example:

```
$('#SomeDivWithLinks').load('whatever.php #DivToLoad',function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault():
        alert('this totally superworks');
    });
});
```

If not performed in the callback function, your jQuery code will never see the new content as able to be manipulated.

Edit: as long as your callback function does not require parameters, you can just have it like this:

```
function doSomething() {
    alert('happy times!');
}

$('#SomeDivWithLinks').load('whatever.php #DivToLoad',doSomething);
```

Comment: It's better to take that click handler out of the `.load` callback. Delegate the click handler to an element that will be present in the DOM at the time the `.on` handler is bound. If none is present use the `document` to delegate the click to.

Comment: oh yeah, preferrably this would be an outside function called rather than have the function be there itself ... as mentioned, its a terribly simplistic answer for space reasons. i think the idea still gets across.